# Why Application request limit reached #4 is received?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

171 calls were initated during last day, it is less then 600 call per 600 sec. How is it I get `Application request limit reached` message? If this an app restriction, then why other users does not receive same message? I checked other SO answers, they does not help. Both `Application Rate Limit` and `User Rate Limit` seems fine. Facebook Help Community is sucks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is not about number of calls. The error message specifically says it is about the number of page assets the app can access on behalf of the current user.

Comment: Hi! But here I am calling `accounts` not `event/pages` or something. Why is accounts limited? Funny .. half day left since last call, and `accounts` is still down for this user. Is it normal?

Comment: To prevent some sort of abuse, probably? Don’t know, you’d have to ask Facebook. Is this app in live mode, or still dev? If the latter, and you need this for testing, one of the bug reports I found relating to this suggests the problem can be avoided by using `limit=3`

Comment: Ah, thanks. `limit=3` solved the problem.